# number of matrices with max eignevalue greater than determinant

Tags: probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I'm thinking about random matrices and probabilities of relationships between matrix properties. As an example made up problem, sayI want to count the number of matrices where the max eigenvalue is greater than the determinant of the matrix.

For simplicity, let's restrict ourselves to small matrices with only a few values. Let's say for now we care about 2x2 matrices, and let's just say the values of the elements can only be integers {-k, -k+1, ..., -1, 0, +1, ..., K-1, k} (unless you know how to provide an answer for the continuous case, then feel free to use continuous values). Choose whatever k you want that is reasonable, maybe 5 [still have (2*5+1)^4 ~15K possible matrices]. Then let's say each element is drawn uniformly at random to make a matrix and then we find its eigenvalue, the determinant, and/or other matrix properties.

As an example question I'm interested in: for how many of those matrices is the max eigenvalue > determinant? Or if you cannot give me a combinatorially exact expression, I'll settle for an approximation. Any insights in solving this would be cool.

Comment: It's uncountable without restrictions.

Do you know what the product of the eigenvalues of a matrix is? (in terms of it's determinant)

Comment: sure, prod eigs is det, sum eigs is trace, etc.

Comment: yeah if you want to include more constraints I'm ok with that, e.g. restrict to class of symmetric matrices or something...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the largest modulus of the eigenvalue is greater than the absolute value of the determinant? 
So for a 2x2 matrix, the other eigenvalue must have modulus less than 1.
So this question is equivalent to finding conditions for which a 2x2 matrix has an eigenvalue with modulus less than 1.

Comment: but actually as I defined the problem so far, I think it is countable. If we did the simplified case mentioned with integer values on [-K,K] then there is only (2K+1)^(N^2) possible matrices to consider.

Comment: True, good point about the 2x2 case.

Comment: For 2x2 matrices with your restrictions, you can probably count the number since the eigenvalues can be easily calculated from the Trace and Determinant http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21b_fall_04/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html . Doesn't seem impossible but could be some work. Once you find possible values of trace and determinant that |eigenvalue|<1, then you just have to find the number of matrices with that trace and determinant.